# How to deploy an Azure VM with Custom Data and an 'attached' VHD in ARM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-rm-template

How would I deploy a linux VM to azure with custom data, in addition to using a VHD in my storage account as the OS disk?

In Azure Classic, I can add a custom data parameter to my deployment. See 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-classic-inject-custom-data.

So, my goal is to do the same in Azure Resource Manager. In addition, I'm just trying to provide custom data -- I'm not trying to run script through the Script Extension (which is Windows only..).

A series of PowerShell commands or an Azure Template are what I'm looking for.

Comment: define `custom data` please?

Comment: Are you referring to the original "inject VM with up to 64KB of custom binary data during startup" from a few years back? I'm not sure that's even part of the ARM deployment model - you should look into some of the ARM samples available that run custom setup scripts etc. Easy enough to use a script at creation time to copy content. Same for attaching VHD - plenty of samples available.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to see if there was a similar feature in ARM. Would you mind going into detail about running a script at creation time to copy content?

Comment: @Madniz `Custom Script Extension` also supports Linux VMs, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-extensions-customscript). When you create VM, you could use scripts to configure what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This still works with ARM! (I'm using it in a Windows environment, from the Python SDK). A sample Azure Template for Linux is available here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-customdata

Comment: Azure team has recently migrated their quickstart templates to different folders. 
Here is the updated URL: 

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/templates/vm-customdata/